# Host a Zend Framework 2 Application in Shared Hosting

Tags: zend-framework2, web-hosting

I hosted my Zend Framework 2 application in a shared hosting server. I uploaded all the files in root folder that is **public_html** . I put following code in my **index.php** file which is inside The  **public** folder.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Now I am trying to browse my application like **test.com/public**  and getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (test) could not be initialized.' in /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175 Stack trace: 

#0 /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(149): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))    
#1 /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('test') 
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
#4 /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Z in /home/nowphp/public_html/zend_test/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

I tried a lot but failed to fix the problem. Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you developed it on your local machine first, does it work okay there?

Comment: Thanks @TimFountain for your reply. Yes, I developed it in local machine and it is working fine there.

Comment: In that case it's most likely to be a case sensitivity issue. What is the full path (including filename) to your test module's `Module.php`?

Comment: Thanks @TimFountain for your precious reply. You guessed right, it is case sensitivity issue.

Could you please say How can I remove **public** word from URL ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the files inside public folder to the root i.e public_html. Then create a folder behind root (suppose folder named **zf2project**) and copy all your folder except public folder into it.

Then edit your index.php file

```
chdir("zf2project/".dirname(__DIR__));
```

Btw can you provide the link to your site.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Nomman pat. I tried like this....    

* Put all the files inside public folder to the `root` i.e public_html.   

* Then create a folder in root named **zf2project**.  

* Put all the files of my project inside **zf2project** except public folder.    

*Edited index.php file with `chdir("zf2project/".dirname(__DIR__));` .  


But this is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post because I had the same question.

One thing that I tried, that seems to be working is creating a symbolic link from your `public_html` directory to your `public` directory within your project directory.

To use the URL: example.com/~user/Application

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ ln -s /path/to/project/public Application
```

To use the URL: example.com/~user

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s /path/to/project/public public_html
```

**This assumes that ~/public_html doesn't already exist.**

I'm not sure if there are any negative repercussions with this method.